# Python 3.x: User using enter to input user's list vertically while using a loop

Tags: python

My task is to have the user input an unlimited amount of words while using enter.

Example:

(this is where the program asks the user to input names)

Please input names one by one.

Input END after you've entered the last name.

(this is where the user would input the names)

Sarah

Tyler

Matthew

END

(by pressing enter, they are entering the names into a list until they enter END)

I'm not sure where the coding for this will be. I assume I would use a while loop but I'm not sure how. Thanks.

I'm really really new to programming and I'm really lost. This is what I have so far:

```
def main() :
      name = []
      print("Please input names one-by-one for validation.")
      diffPasswords = input("Input END after you've entered the last name.")
      while True :
           if
```

Comment: Please show what you've attempted so far, and where (specifically) you are stuck

Comment: Is that the complete code? your last line is simply `if` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below while loop:

```
l = []
while 'END' not in l:
   l.append(input('Name: '))
l.pop()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Name: Sarah
Name: Tyler
Name: Matthew
Name: END
['Sarah', 'Tyler', 'Matthew']
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simply done with a while loop.

```
name_list=[]
while True:
    i = input('enter').rstrip()
    if i == 'END':
        break
    name_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically keep on getting a new line but if it equals END\n then stop. The \n is from the enter. Otherwise add it to the list but make sure to omit the last character because that is the newline character(\n) from the enter.

```
    import sys
    list = []

    while True:
        c = sys.stdin.readline()

        if c == "END\n":
            break

        else:
            list.append(c[0:-1])
    print(list)
```